Conditionally omit protocol from hyperlink texts based on URL (Cambridge University Press style)
The Cambridge University Press style guide mandates the following formatting for URLs:

’http://’ and ‘https://’ should not be included before ‘www.’. However, if a URL does not include ‘www.’ then the ‘http://’ must be included.

Presumably the last sentence also applies to URLs that begin with https, but not with any other protocols.  So, when using the hyperref package, the following six URLs would need to be typeset and hyperlinked as follows:

http://www.example.com → www.example.com
https://www.example.com → www.example.com
http://example.com → http://example.com
https://example.com → https://example.com
ftp://www.example.com → ftp://www.example.com
ftp://example.com → ftp://example.com

Is there an easy way of defining a single \url-like command that automatically sets the correct link text and link target for its argument according to these rules?  Or is there perhaps a package that already provides such a command?

Using xstring:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myurl}{m}{
  \IfSubStr{#1}{https}%
    {%
      \IfSubStr{#1}{www}{\StrDel{#1}{https://}}{#1}%
    }%
    {%
      \IfSubStr{#1}{http}%
        {%
          \IfSubStr{#1}{www}{\StrDel{#1}{http://}}{#1}%
        }{#1}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \verb|\myurl{http://www.example.com}| & \myurl{http://www.example.com} \\
  \verb|\myurl{https://www.example.com}| & \myurl{https://www.example.com} \\
  \verb|\myurl{http://example.com}| & \myurl{http://example.com} \\
  \verb|\myurl{https://example.com}| & \myurl{https://example.com} \\
  \verb|\myurl{ftp://www.example.com}| & \myurl{ftp://www.example.com} \\
  \verb|\myurl{ftp://example.com}| & \myurl{ftp://example.com}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}



I'm afraid this doesn't work for a number of reasons: (1) It looks for "http(s)" anywhere in the URL rather than only in the protocol. (2) It looks for "www" anywhere in the URL rather than only at the start of the host name. (3) It doesn't hyperlink the URLs the way \href and \url do. (4) It doesn't handle special characters in URLs the way \url and \nolinkurl do. Some of these problems are easier to solve than others. I'm particularly stumped by the last two, since \nolinkurl doesn't like arguments containing \StrDel.

Maybe you should try the l3regex module.@Psychonaut
